# Left command key does not work

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

My left <kbd>⌘</kbd> (command key) doesn't respond, while the right <kbd>⌘</kbd> key works fine.

- my Mac: MacBook Pro (Retina, Mid 2012)
- on keyboard viewer: when I click left <kbd>⌘</kbd> no respond on keyboard viewer, but right <kbd>⌘</kbd> and all other keys have.
- I have opened the left `⌘` key, nothing seems wrong with it. (The left <kbd>⌘</kbd> has no physical damage.)

Anyone know what is wrong with my left <kbd>⌘</kbd> key?

Comment: Your keyboard is broken.  You need to take it in for service and have the keyboard replaced.

Comment: Thanks @Allan, I guess you are right, do you know how much it coast ?

Comment: @Allan, I'm having a similar problem with my keyboard--do you know if you *can* get a keyboard replaced for a Mid-2012 MBP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try restarting in Recovery mode by holding the right command key and R during power-up. If that works (i.e. you boot into Recovery mode), then try doing the same with the left command key.

If that fails, you have a defect keyboard that needs replacement.

Comment: Hei, @jksoegaard, thanks for your help. I tried your method, the right key works but not the left key. I will take it to the service when I get time :)